# How to copy .2D file from web to S3 bucket? Failing on decode

Tags: python, amazon-s3, copy

I am copying files from a website to a S3 bucket.  Everything else is copying fine, even odd extensions that I haven't heard of before.  The extension that I am having problems with is ".2D".

Currently using this code, and it is working for all but the .2D files. Might be a VERSACAD file.
Anyone work with this file or know how to figure out how to work with this?  No, I can't include an example.

It is failing on the r.data.decode("utf'8") line.  Using "utf-16" doesn't work either.

```
data=r.data.decode("utf-8")
key_path="downloaded_docs/{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}".format(year,str(month).zfill(2),str(day).zfill(2),docname)
```

To save to s3 bucket:

```
s3.Object('s3_bucket_name',key_path).put(Body=data)
```

**WHAT WORKED**
I ended up having to do the following, but it worked.  Thanks!!

```
if extracted_link.endswith('.2D'):
    r=http.request("GET", url_to_file, preload_content=False)
    # to get binary data
    text_b=r.data
    filepath=<filepath>
    s3_client.upload_fileobj(io.BytesIO(text_b),Bucket=<bucketname>,Key=filepath)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upload it in binary

from file path

```py
import boto3
client = boto3.client("s3")
client.upload_file(2D_filepath, bucket, key)
```

from file object

```py
import boto3, io
client = boto3.client("s3")
client.upload_fileobj(io.BytesIO(b"binary data"), bucket, key)
```

Comment: I'll try that after this code finishes running. Thanks.